# How do I deploy a website that is using Strapi as backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hosting, strapi

How do I deploy a website that is using Strapi as the backend? I've tried hosting the frontend (react) on Digital Ocean and then hosting Strapi separately (also on Digital Ocean) but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I am missing something? My site only loads content when I am fetching from Strapi that is hosted on localhost1337.

Here is the code https://github.com/Beewong1998/pEt-Commerce

I've tried to troubleshoot this for hours now so any help would be massively appreciated!!